# Php fpm и nginx

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

Пытался понять что такое пхп фпм и зачем он используется в связке с nginx но не особо понял. Почему при использовании апача не нужен фпм? А именно с nginx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

для интерпретации скриптов, написанных на языке *php*, нужна программа-интерпретатор. ни *nginx*, ни *apache* интерпретировать такие скрипты не умеют.

- для *nginx* в этом случае обычно [используют](http://php.net/manual/ru/install.unix.nginx.php) интерфейс [fastcgi](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI) для запуска интерпретатора php-fpm (fpm == fastcgi process manager).
- для *apache* в этом случае обычно [используют соответствующий модуль](http://php.net/manual/ru/install.unix.apache2.php) (включающий в себя интерпретатор *php*). хотя и [использование php-fpm через fastcgi-модуль тоже вполне допустимо](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PHP-FPM).

---

> что такое пхп фпм

это интерпретатор *php*, собранный таким образом, чтобы предоставлять интерфейс [fastcgi](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI). ну и с «[несколькими дополнительными возможностями обычно используемыми для высоконагруженных сайтов](http://php.net/manual/ru/install.fpm.php)».

Comment: У apache я так понимаю это mod-php?

Comment: насколько мне известно, у модуля с интерпретатором php для apache нет «канонического» названия. в разных дистрибутивах опакетированный модуль называют по-разному.