# Несколько Php версий для Apache

Tags: apache2, apache2.2

Привет всем!

Есть ли способ запустить одну версию `Apache 2.2` с двумя версиями php, так чтобы 1 `VirtualHost` обрабатывал соединения с `php 5.3` например, а другой `VirtualHost` c `php 7.0` например.

Можно ли для этого использовать `LoadModule` директив, так как в документации сказано что они могут быть использованы на уровне `VirtualHost`

Comment: да, можно, конечно. но интерпретацией php будет заниматься не модуль apache, а отдельные процессы php-fpm. [документация](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PHP-FPM) // прочитайте ещё [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/644209/178576) для общей информации.

Answer (score -1):

Да, можно, у меня так работает.

Надо поставить 2 Апача в разные папки, настроить на разные порты (80,443 - 81,444) в настройках

Comment: Нет, мне нужна 1 версия работающая с двумя версиями php.

Comment: PHP это модуль - Apache. Нельзя подключать два разных модуля в зависимости от чего-то... Это надо как-то два файла настроек, да и жонглировать ими... Если и можно , то мне невдомек...