# В чем разница между php и php –fpm?

Tags: php, nginx, веб-сервер

Мне поставлена задача установить на сервер связку nginx и php- fpm.  Я не очень понял чем php-fpm отличается от ядра php, написано что nginx самостоятельно обрабатывает статику  а обработку php скриптов отдает php-fpm.  Я всегда считал, что ядро php собственно и занимается тем что получает запрос от веб-сервера на обработку php скритов, обрабатывает и отдает результат назад.

Comment: Внутри php-fpm есть php-ядро, так что пытаться что-то тут сравнивать бессмысленно

Comment: php-fpm это всего лишь FastCGI-сервер, один из вариантов получения и обработки запросов. А что вы имеете в виду под фразой "ядро php .. получает запрос" - непонятно

Comment: Я с apache работал. То что я до этого видел: устанавливается apache, скачивается php (https://www.php.net/downloads.php - это я и имел ввиду под ядром), в apache указывается путь до php. Судя по всему то что я написал это CGI, менее производительная технология при большом кол-ве запросов к серверу.

Comment: Да, в CGI просто запускается обычная программа php, апач пихает всю информацию о запросе в stdin и в переменные окружения программе, а она выдаёт ответ в stdout. Запуск программы каждый раз заново это медленно, поэтому php-fpm будет получше. Хотя вообще в апаче есть libapache2-mod-php, и странно, что вы не использовали его

Comment: Может ответ напишете? Благодаря тому что я в гугл вбил FastCGI-сервер, нашел что есть что. Я так понял у apache по умолчанию CGI? Честно говоря почему не apach я сказать не могу, не мой выбор, но судя по всему планируется большое кол-во одновременных подключений, с чем nginx справляется лучше как я понял.

Comment: [близкая тематика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/644156/178576)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Есть сферический PHP в вакууме, `Zend Engine`. Он именно что в вакууме, не имеет никаких средств взаимодействия с пользователем без реализации некоторого интерфейса `SAPI` - `Server API`.

[В дереве исходных текстов](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/PHP-7.3/sapi) есть несколько штатных реализаций `SAPI`:

- интерфейс для запуска из командной строки `CLI`
- модуль для веб-сервера apache
- интерфейс для работы через CGI интерфейс
- FPM как самостоятельная реализация FastCGI интерфейса

Ну и некоторые другие.

Поэтому бессмысленно сравнивать php с его же собственным SAPI. Каждый из SAPI ведёт себя по-разному, что продиктовано требованиями к взаимодействию с внешним миром.

---

В контексте nginx - речь может идти только о FPM. nginx не умеет CGI, очевидно не может работать с модулем apache, CLI тоже неуместен. Временами настраивается цепочка nginx -> apache -> модуль PHP для apache, где статические файлы раздаёт nginx, за динамику отвечает apache. Но зачем здесь apache, если есть fastCGI? Просто лишнее звено, ещё раз форматирующее и разбирающее запрос.

Почему сейчас в большинстве случаев используется nginx? Он легче и проще держит множество соединений с клиентами.

> Я так понял у apache по умолчанию CGI?

По умолчанию apache вовсе не обрабатывает скрипты. Что-то было настроено явным образом в конфигурации веб-сервера. Возможно не вами (а, например, инсталлятором), но настроено было. Угадать что именно - затруднительно. Я бы ожидал использование модуля `libapache2-mod-php`.

Comment: Вот нравятся мне ваши ответы, да только жаль, что мало вы их постите :) P.S.: _Строитель_